# Erratic behaviour in a makefile resulting in re-building targets

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm using makefiles to structure a data analysis pipeline consisting of various steps such as extracting data, sampling and modelling. However, when I create an additional "upper-level" makefile (such as modelling) that depends on others, and I try to run make again (either on the new makefile or any other upper-level makefiles), it tries to re-build everything again from the lowest-level makefile targets.

In the code below I show the "lowest level" makefile and another one (makefile.sample that includes the first one):

Makefile

```
all: 
    make $(DATA_TRN) 
    make $(Y_TRN)
    
# dates
SNAP_TRN := 2019-06-18
SNAP_TST := 2019-07-24

# Targets
TARGET_CLASS = m1_vol
TARGET_SURV = m1_qty
TARGET_INIT = act_qty
END_DUR = 1

# dirs
DIR_DATA := data
DIR_CONFIG := configs
 
# data files for training and predict
DATA_TRN := $(DIR_DATA)/processed/churnvol_train_$(SNAP_TRN).csv
DATA_TST := $(DIR_DATA)/processed/churnvol_test_$(SNAP_TST).csv
# labels
Y_TRN := $(DIR_DATA)/processed/label_train_$(SNAP_TRN).csv
Y_TST := $(DIR_DATA)/processed/label_test_$(SNAP_TST).csv

# Config files
CONFIG_PANEL := $(DIR_CONFIG)/config_panel.yaml
CONFIG_INPUT := $(DIR_CONFIG)/config_inpute.yaml
FEATS := $(DIR_CONFIG)/featimp_churnvol.csv
                
# Generates a clean dataset (inputed and one hot encoded)
$(DATA_TRN): $(CONFIG_INPUT) $(FEATS) | $(DATA_DIR)
    python src/_buildDataset.py --train-file $(DATA_TRN) \
                                --test-file $(DATA_TST) \
                                --train-date $(SNAP_TRN) \
                                --test-date $(SNAP_TST) \
                                --config-panel $(CONFIG_PANEL) \
                                --config-input $< \
                                --feats $(lastword $^)  

$(Y_TRN): $(DATA_TRN) | $(DATA_DIR) 
python src/_extractColumns.py --data $< \
                              --columns $(TARGET_INIT),$(TARGET_CLASS),$(TARGET_SURV) \
                              --file $@
clean:
    -rm -rf $(DATA_TST) $(DATA_TRN) $(Y_TRN) $(Y_TST)

.PHONY: all clean
```

Makefile.sample.u1

```
include Makefile

sample: 
    make -f Makefile.sample.$(SAMPLE_NAME) $(DATA_TRN_SAMPLE)

SAMPLE_NAME = u1   
MIN_RATIO = 0.333333 # ratio of minority class for undersampling
DATA_TRN_SAMPLE := $(DIR_DATA)/processed/churnvol_train_$(SAMPLE_NAME)_$(SNAP_TRN).csv


$(DATA_TRN_SAMPLE): $(DATA_TRN) | $(DATA_DIR)
    python ./src/_generate_sample_u1.py --data-train $< \
                                        --data-file $@ \
                                        --min-ratio $(MIN_RATIO) \
                                        --end-feat $(TARGET_SURV) \
                                        --end-dur $(END_DUR)
                                                                             
.PHONY: sample
```

From these 2 makefiles, I'm assuming that `make` only needs to rebuild $(DATA_TRN) if either $(CONFIG_INPUT) or $(FEATS) changed after $(DATA_TRN) right? The problem is that both timestamps show a previous date from the target $(DATA_TRN) and when I run `make all` it still rebuilds the target. `src/_buildDataset.py` also shows a previous date. I've tried to debug and running `make $(DATA_TRN)` returns a `$(DATA_TRN) is up to date.` message. However, when I run `make $(Y_TRN)` it rebuild $(DATA_TRN), which I find odd. This also means that when I run `make -f Makefile.sample.u1 sample`, it also goes on to rebuild $(DATA_TRN). Can someone help me figure out if I did something wrong? Or other ways to debug, such as knowing exactly what file `make` marked as "changed". Thank you

Comment: Yes, that was the call I made when I first encountered this problem. Running `make all` also results in rebuilding, and `make $(Y_TRN)` as well

Comment: If I replace the Python scripts with `touch $@`, everything works as expected. `make data/processed/churnvol_train_2019-06-18.csv
make[1]: Entering directory '/mnt/c/Users/08PFM237/source/code'
make[1]: 'data/processed/churnvol_train_2019-06-18.csv' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/mnt/c/Users/08PFM237/source/code'
make data/processed/label_train_2019-06-18.csv
make[1]: Entering directory '/mnt/c/Users/08PFM237/source/code'
make[1]: 'data/processed/label_train_2019-06-18.csv' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/mnt/c/Users/08PFM237/source/code'`

Comment: This is not related to your problem here, but you should never use `make` directly inside makefiles.  Always use the `$(MAKE)` variable.

Comment: @MadScientist what is your opinion on recursive `make` due to dynamic target and prereq names? Better to rearrange and get rid of the recursive invocation, or do as shown?

Comment: It's almost always better to avoid recursive invocation, but sometimes using it greatly simplifies the makefile so I don't categorically rule it out.  Here it doesn't seem like it makes much difference in how the system runs, so if the OP prefers to arrange things this way it seems fine.

Comment: If it works when you use `touch` then it seems like something is definitely weird about how the python scripts update files.  `make -d` will tell you why make decided to rebuild files: which files were out of date etc.  You didn't specify which version of GNU make you're using but just to note, you need at least version 3.80 to use order-only prerequisites.  Probably this isn't your problem or you'd get errors about `|` as a prerequisite.

Comment: If literally *everything* gets rebuilt in the fault case, then you can be confident that at least all those targets that do not have any built files among their prerequisites appear to `make` to be out of date.

Comment: Is it intentional that you have references to a variable `DATA_DIR` that is not set anywhere in the makefiles presented?  Are those maybe supposed to be `DIR_DATA`, instead?

Comment: Thank you for your help @MadScientist, @vroomfondel and @john-bollinger. Regarding the use of `make` inside the file, I use it to simplify the targets calls, so instead of calling the name of the file, I simply call `make ... sample`, `make ... train`, etc, is this fine (using GNU make 3.82). @john-bollinger thank you for the correction, it's indeed `DIR_DATA`.

Comment: I will correct the `DIR_DATA` and rebuild everything from scratch, will edit my question if I can pinpoint the problem better.